# Python code creates more than Synchronous timers fired once with different actions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to write a python code including GUI (tkinter) that runs 2 or even more timers at the same time with different actions/commands, but with the same "Start" button. The problem in my code below is the 2 timers are created but they are sequentially running. Can I create 2 timers with different time set running synchronously.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

#Create interface#

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Countdown Timer")


#declare variables for Timer1
hrString1 = StringVar()
minuteString1 = StringVar()
secString1 = StringVar()

#Set String to default values 
hrString1.set("00")
minuteString1.set("00")
secString1.set("00")

#Get User Input
hourTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString1).place(x=170, y=100) 
minuteTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minuteString1).place(x=220, y=100)  
secondTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString1).place(x=270, y=100) 

#declare variables
hrString2 = StringVar()
minString2 = StringVar()
secString2 = StringVar()

#Set String to default values 
hrString2.set("00")
minString2.set("00")
secString2.set("00")

#Get User Input
hourTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString2).place(x=170, y=180) 
minuteTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minString2).place(x=220, y=180)  
secondTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString2).place(x=270, y=180) 


def runTimer1():
    try:
        clockTime = int(hrString1.get())*3600 + int(minuteString1.get())*60 + int(secString1.get()) 
    except:
        print("Incorrect values")
        
    while(clockTime > -1):
        totalMinutes, totalSeconds = divmod(clockTime, 60)
        totalHours = 0  #initialize
        if(totalMinutes>60):
            totalHours, totalMinutes = divmod(totalMinutes, 60)
          
        hrString1.set("{0:2d}".format(totalHours))
        minuteString1.set("{0:2d}".format(totalMinutes))
        secString1.set("{0:2d}".format(totalSeconds))

        #update the interface with each iteration 
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        #time expires 
        if(clockTime == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("", "time One has expired!")  #Run Command 1
        clockTime -= 1

def runTimer2():
    try:
        clockTime2 = int(hrString2.get())*3600 + int(minString2.get())*60 + int(secString2.get()) 
    except:
        print("Incorrect values")
        
    while(clockTime2 > -1):
        totalMinutes, totalSeconds = divmod(clockTime2, 60)
        totalHours = 0  #initialize
        if(totalMinutes>60):
            totalHours, totalMinutes = divmod(totalMinutes, 60)
          
        hrString2.set("{0:2d}".format(totalHours))
        minString2.set("{0:2d}".format(totalMinutes))
        secString2.set("{0:2d}".format(totalSeconds))

        #update the interface with each iteration 
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        #time expires 
        if(clockTime2 == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("", "time Two has expired!")  #Run Command 2
        clockTime2 -= 1


setTimeButton = Button(root, text='START', bd='5', command=lambda: [runTimer1(), runTimer2()]).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)        

#Keep Loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use `while` loops or `time.sleep` with `tkinter` like that. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) instead.

Comment: I added .after method and added 2 tasks (2 threads) but the problem is the time in "Entry" doesn't update '